# How can I look directly at the center of the TextureCoordinateFunction?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

By manually adjusting the coefficients inside `TextureCoordinateFunction` I can get the numbers on each ball to sort of face the camera:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Opacity@0.5, Blue, Cuboid[{-2, -2, -2}, {2, 2, 0}],
  Opacity@1, Sequence @@ MapThread[
    Translate[
      SphericalPlot3D[#3, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
        Mesh -> None, 
        TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, 0.3*#2 + 0.7*#3} &), 
        PlotStyle -> 
         Texture[Show@
           Graphics@Text@Style[ToString@#1, 100]]][[1]], #2] &, {{8, 
      5, 13, 3},
     {{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.4,
       0.2}}]
  }, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {-5, -9, 3}, 
 ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, PreserveImageOptions -> False]
```

[image]

How can I script the coordinates inside `TextureCoordinateFunction` so the numbers are facing the `ViewPoint`, while preserving the orientation of the cube?

The solution from [Viewing a city's coordinates from above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645936/viewing-a-citys-coordinates-from-above) doesn't take into account that I also want to see the cube from a particular perspective.

**Update: this almost works:** (But how to preserve the shape of the letter? I can't get it to work with slots 1-3 of the `TextureCoordinateFunction`.)

```
With[{viewpoint = {-5, -9, 3}}, Graphics3D[{
   Opacity@0.5, Blue, Cuboid[{-2, -2, -2}, {2, 2, 0}],
   Opacity@1, Sequence @@ MapThread[
     With[{textpos = 
         CoordinateTransform[ "Cartesian" -> "Spherical", 
            Normalize[#2 - viewpoint]][[2 ;; 3]]/\[Pi]},
       Translate[
        SphericalPlot3D[#3, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
          Mesh -> None, 
          TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({(#4 - textpos[[1]] - 
                0.2), (#5 - textpos[[2]] + 0.15)} &), 
          PlotStyle -> 
           Texture[
            Rotate[Show@Graphics@Text@Style[ToString@#1, 100], 
             90 Degree]]][[1]], #2]] &, {
      {8, 5, 13, 3},
      {{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}},
      {0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2}
      }]
   }, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> viewpoint, 
  ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, PreserveImageOptions -> False]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A possible approach is to use `Text` as `Graphics3D` primitive (it is automatically re-oriented to face the viewer and it is not blocked by other primitives):

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity@0.5, Blue, Cuboid[{-2, -2, -2}, {2, 2, 0}], 
  Opacity@1, Sequence @@ 
   MapThread[Translate[
    {SphericalPlot3D[#3, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None][[1]], 
     Text[Style[ToString@#1, Black, FontSize -> Scaled[#3/8]]]}, #2] &,
   {{8, 5, 13, 3}, {{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, 
    {0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2}}]}, 
 Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {-5, -9, 3}, 
 ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, PreserveImageOptions -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, but it doesn't preserve the wrapping of the numbers on each ball. Is Text in Graphics3D just pasting a 2D letter on top, or actually mapping it to the surface? I tried looking at the GraphicsComplex of your output and it's not clear to me what's going on, it does seem to be converting TextureCoordinateFunction into VertexTextureCoordinates which gives me some idea maybe it is actually keeping track of the 3D positions to render each number. If so, I think it should be possible to simply plug that into the TextureCoordinateFunction instead to get the desired result?

Comment: @ninemileskid, Re "Is Text in Graphics3D just pasting a 2D letter on top, or actually mapping it to the surface?", it is the former.

Comment: Well, fiddlesticks.